# Bourne Shell do while loop returns all the data but has two errors no such file or directory and repeats the shell name

Tags: linux, files, scripting, directory

The idea of my loop is to print the first digit of every line of a file.
The file being this:

```
256-56-8411     Bob     3.61    Junior          CS
471-44-7458     Tim     3.45    Senior          CE
326-56-4286     Rajesh  2.97    Freshman        TE
548-66-1124     Eric    2.88    Sophomore       EE
447-21-3599     John    2.51    Junior          CS
911-41-1256     Rebecca 3.92    Senior          CS
854-22-6372     Robin   2.45    Freshman        TE
```

And the output after running the script is:

```
    This is a script that analyses student data from input file students.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------------
./student_script: line 8: 2
4
3
5
4
9
8: No such file or directory
7 is the number of students in the input file.
```

And lastly, the code is:

```
echo "This is a script that analyses student data from input file $1"
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
studentCount=`wc -l < $1 `
tempFile=`cut -c1 $1`
while read n
do
echo "$n"
done < $tempFile

echo "$studentCount is the number of students in the input file."
```

After I get this fixed I plan on using the while loop to check if the first digit is a four or not and then stating how many ID's (first column) don't start with a 4.

I don't mind learning about a cleaner solution then my approach, but this is for a class and I don't think we have learned a lot of it. During my journey I saw a lot of similar stuff with awk, but we haven't learned awk at all yet.

But yeah, basically I did get all the data I wanted from my loop, except it added those two extra bits.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote in this line:

```
tempFile=`cut -c1 $1`
```

does not create a file called `tempFile`. Therefore you can not read from it.

You may change that line to:

```
cut -c1 "$1" > tempFile
```

And a file called `tempFile` will be created for the `while read` loop to read. Do not use `$tempFile` in that loop, as the variable `$tempfile` is null (does not exist). Use something like (no $):

```
done < tempFile
```

However, the simple command `cut -c1 "$1"` will write all the first characters from the source file, just execute this to see it:

```
cut -c1 "sourcefile"
```

Knowing that, you do not need a tempFile to hold the values, just use a here document.

Using a here doc and cleaning some other issues in your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "This is a script that analyses student data from input file $1"
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
studentCount="$(wc -l < "$1" )"

while read n
do
    echo "$n"
done <<-_avoid_a_file_
$(cut -c1 "$1")
_avoid_a_file_

echo "$studentCount is the number of students in the input file."
```

It is a good practice to use a she-bang (#!) to indicate which interpreter should run the code. In this case I assumed that you wanted `sh` because of the mention of `Bourne shell`. Please note that the original Bourne shell is quite old (~1979) and that many improvements have been added to more recent shells (ksh, bash, mksh, zsh, etc).

Comment: Thank you! I was getting pretty frustrated. I think my class is going to use multiple shells, but we started with bourne. But what was wrong with my studentCount variable that deemed the changes? Just good practice? Thanks again.

Comment: @Shawn It was a simple change from backticks ` ... ` (now deprecated) to $(....). If you want to know the detailed reasoning for such change just [follow the POSIX link in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4708569/2350426).

Comment: Backticks are not deprecated, but `$(...)` was added. Some shells recently started to correctly support `$(...)`. For this reason, it is still recommended to use backticks for non-nested calls to get portability. In special as `$(...)` does not work currectly in `zsh` that seems to be popular.